# Powershell - Delete every other line in all the files within a directory

Tags: powershell

I'm still very new to Powershell. I ran some edited code that was supposed to replace some text in a file, however it didn't work as expected and instead duplicated every line in the file. Code for those that need a chuckle below.

This wouldn't be so bad except it did it for over 1000 documents in the folder, so, I need to write a script to undo the damage caused. I've googled it to death and can find lots of things doing similar things, but nothing I can take and rearrange for my needs. So can anyone help?

Here's my original code:

```
function ChangeText{
    $obj = Get-ChildItem -recurse -Include *.xml  -path "************"
    foreach($item in $obj)
    {
        (Get-Content $item.PSPath) |
        Foreach-Object { 
            $_ -replace "Unwanted Text", "Wanted Text" 
            $_ -replace "Other Unwanted Text", "Wanted Text" ##This line is the line I stupidly added which caused the issue 
        } |
        Set-Content $item.PSPath
    }
}

ChangeText
```

Example: I need to turn:

```
Help Me please
Help Me please
I made a mistake with the script
I made a mistake with a script
and I need your help to fix it. 
and I need your help to fix it.
```

Into:

```
Help Me please
I made a mistake with the script
and I need your help to fix it.
```

I can't rely on just removing duplicate lines as the original replace text worked on the original line so some of the files are showing duplicate lines and some are showing 1 original line and one changed line.

It doesn't matter which of the lines is kept and which is discarded as I can run the original script against it to change the text again (without my changes)

Can someone help?

Comment: Manu has posted a good solution. For the love of code, take a backup next time.

Comment: Yes, A backup was taken, unfortunately we didn't realise a scheduled task was still running and filling the folder with new files from after our backup, so our backup is missing hundred of newly added files. So it's not really helped our position.

Comment: As mentioned below,removing duplicate code won't help

Comment: Noted. I missed that as well. Check out Chris's answer. You can achieve the same thing by changing the body of your `ForEach-Object` to `$i++ ;  if($i%2){$_}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use modulus to kill off alternating lines.

```
$i = 0
Get-Content file.txt | Where-Object { $i % 2 -eq 0; $i++ }
```

Comment: May need to start $i at 1, that should allow it to keep the first instance of each pair of lines. Test, test, test should go without saying at this point.

Comment: Thank you all, between your answers I've managed to put together a script and fixed the issue. And made a note about the scheduled task so it doesn't happen again. It won't let me upvote comments but I would if I could :/

Comment: You need to go answer a lot more questions and link to this answer. I found a ton of other solutions that were much more complex than this for how to get every other object from a collection. Thank you.